# Guardar sesión de usuario con SharedPreferences

Tags: android, webservice, session, sharedpreferences

Necesito guardar la sesión de los usuarios, mi app esta conectada a un **WebService** he intentado implementar **SharedPreferences** para crear una ***"session"***, sin embargo no ha resultado. Si alguien me podria orientar o tener una mejor idea.

Guardo el *usuario* y su *contraseña* después que el `Asynctask` valide los datos

```
 if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
            {

                final String usuario = editusuario.getText().toString();
                final String clave= editpass.getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bienvenido: "+usuario,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                session.createLoginSession(usuario,clave ); // aqui intento guerdar los datos para sesión 

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,cronometro.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                MainActivity.this.finish();
```

Hago referencia dentro de la clase que contiene el `Asyntask`

```
session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
```

Y la clase `SessionManager` es :

```
public class SessionManager {

    SharedPreferences pref;


    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


    Context _context;


    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;


    private static final String PREF_NAME = "reg";


    private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";


    public static final String KEY_NAME = "Name";


    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "Email";


    public SessionManager(Context context){
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }


    public void createLoginSession(String Name, String Email){

        editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);


        editor.putString(KEY_NAME, Name);


        editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, Email);


        editor.commit();
    }


    public void checkLogin(){

        if(!this.isLoggedIn()){

            Intent i = new Intent(_context, cronometro.class);

            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


            _context.startActivity(i);
        }

    }




    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();

        user.put(KEY_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));


        user.put(KEY_EMAIL, pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));


        return user;
    }


    public void logoutUser(){

        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();


        Intent i = new Intent(_context, MainActivity.class);

        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


        _context.startActivity(i);
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
    }
}
```

***El problema es que como le paso el usuario y la contraseña del servidor para que compare los guardados.***

**NOTA: HE CAMBIADO EL ENFOQUE DEL PROBLEMA, UNA POSIBLE SOLUCIÓN LA HE AÑADIDO EN LA SESIÓN RESPUESTAS**

Comment: A ver a ver. El servidor te retorna un usuario y contraseña y quieres comprar esos resultados con los que tienes guardados en el SharePreference?

Comment: Y como debe recibir el WebService  los datos guardados, tienes un método expuesto? es importante indicarlo, esta comparación debe realizarse dentro del WS.

Comment: Si asi es @Einer

Comment: Ese es el problema no se la forma mas adecuada para realizar ese proceso @Jorgesys

Comment: Ya tienes realizado tu WebService, tienes el método para recibir los valores? me parece más un problema de WS que del lado de Android el cual veo correcto.

Comment: Yo estaba haciendo todo por el lado de android, el ws no recibe valores aun @Jorgesys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado la solución, he enfocado el problema de una manera mas simple, aquí mi respuesta por si otro usuario lo necesita. Quiero destacar que es bienvenida cualquier mejora de seguridad o del código.

Primero que nada añado un `Checkbox` a mi formulario **LOGIN** para luego crear dos funciones para este control, la primera la llame `guerdar_estado_boton` que es la siguiente :

```
  public void guardar_estado_boton() {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(ESTADO_BOTON,guardar_pass.isChecked());
        editor.apply();
    }
```

Esta función simplemente guarda el estado del `Checkbox` si esta o no "activado".

Luego creo una segunda funcion llamada `obtener_valor_boton` que es la siguiente :

```
 public boolean obtener_estado_boton(){
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
     return settings.getBoolean(ESTADO_BOTON,false);

  }
```

Esta función obtengo el estado del `Checkbox` si esta activado o no, y por defecto le pase un `false` es decir que no guardara la sesión del usuario

Ahhh y las variables estaticas son :

```
 private static  final String PREFS_KEY = "tu_contexto";
 private static  final String ESTADO_BOTON = "estado.boton";
```

na vez teniendo todo esto funcional, en la actividad de LOGIN antes de que se ejecute todo lo demas dentro de la actividad, use lo siguiente :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       if (obtener_estado_boton()){
           Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,cronometro.class);
           startActivity(intent);
           MainActivity.this.finish();
       }
```

Esto quiere decir que antes que se ejecute otra cosa, verificara si el `checkbox` se guardo como activado o no y si es true, pasara directo a la siguiente actividad, sin pasar por el **LOGIN**.

Ahhh se me escapaba ejecuto la función `guardar_estado_boton()`; en `Asynctask` después de validar e iniciar sesión con el servidor correctamente.

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            // este método se ejecutará en el subproceso de la interfaz de usuario
            pdLoading.dismiss();

            if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
            {

                final String usuario = editusuario.getText().toString();
               // final String clave= editpass.getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bienvenido: "+usuario,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                guardar_estado_boton();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,cronometro.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                MainActivity.this.finish();
```

Comment: Felix, pero donde envías aquí los datos al WS? =0

Comment: La clave esta en el Checkbox, la validación es por la app no por el ws, si el checkbox esta activado, no le volverá a mostrar el login, hasta que cierre sesión(borrar la data), es una solucion simple jaja mejorable claro que si