# Al cerrar la aplicación, se borra lo almacenado con SharePreferences

Tags: android, app, kotlin, sharedpreferences

Buen día, en este momento estoy tratando de guardar con **SharedPreferences** una variable que contiene un **token**, para posteriormente ingresar a un formulario en específico según sea lo que contenga ("" o "**elValordelToken**") con el fin de realizar un auto login.
Estaba probando la aplicación y al parecer al momento de cerrarla se borra lo que había almacenado.
Adjunto parte del código.

```
 val sharedP = getSharedPreferences("userS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        fun keepShared(){
            val editSharedP = sharedP.edit()      
            editSharedP.putString("token",loginObj.token)
            editSharedP.commit()

        }

 var token = response["authToken"].toString();
                            loginObj.token = token
                            keepShared()
                            val pros = Intent(this, Prospectos::class.java)
                            startActivity(pros)
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Yo he hecho esta forma de "auto login" pero encofada de otra manera, usando SharePreferend. Almacena una variable (no token) y funciona perfecto, pero claro es mas seguro usar un token, si quieres te publico la respuesta

Comment: Sí, ¡está bien!

Comment: Intenta llamar el metodo `val sharedP = getSharedPreferences("userS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` dentro de la `fun` y no afuera y dime que pasa.

Answer (score 0):

No lo esta guardando por que en Kotlin es preferible utilizar `apply` en ves de `commit` quedaria de la siguiente manera

```
fun keepShared(){
    val editSharedP = sharedP.edit()
    editSharedP.putString("token",loginObj.token)
    editSharedP.apply()
}
```

trata de crear un solo sharedpreferences y en el guardar lo que necesites.

Answer (score 0):

Yo he usado esta forma singleton en kotlin y me ha funcionado

```
object Singleton{

private const val preferenceName = "kotlinDemo"
private lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
private lateinit var editor: SharedPreferences.Editor

fun instance(context: Context): Preference {
    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(preferenceName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
    return this
}

var sessionStatus: Boolean
    get() = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("sessionStatus", false)
    set(value) {
        editor.putBoolean("sessionStatus", value).commit()
    }
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Yo use un `Checkbox` para verificar si el usuario quería guardar su sesión.

Luego cree 2 funciones, una que **guarda la variable** (true o false) y la segunda que **obtiene la variable**. y luego comparo aquella variable en la actividad ***login*** si es true o false para saltar la autenticacion. a continuación te dejo la [respuesta aquí mas detallada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/115594/guardar-sesi%C3%B3n-de-usuario-con-sharedpreferences) dentro del mismo sitio de Stackoverflow.

Comment: Es buena opción, pero necesito el guardar el token para acceder a unos servicios

Comment: Lo puedes modificar, cambiar la variable del checkbox, es el mismo procedimiento @saheco